# TempData with Sitecore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore

I'm having trouble accessing TempData values on the first redirect back to the same page. The TempData dictionary is empty when I inspect it. TempData should be able to last the first HTTP request so why does it come back as empty? Is there something sitecore specific that I'm missing?

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(InformationViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var Id = Session[SessionCurrentIdKey];

                var mailingAddress = new MailingAddress();
                var contactInformation = new ContactInformation();
                var operatingDetails = new OperatingDetails();

                Mapper.Map(model, mailingAddress);
                Mapper.Map(model, contactInformation);
                Mapper.Map(model, operatingDetails);

                WebApiHelper.Upload("MailingAddress", Id, mailingAddress);
                WebApiHelper.Upload("ContactInformation", Id, contactInformation);
                WebApiHelper.Upload("OperatingDetails", Id, operatingDetails);

                TempData["Message"] = "Successfully updated information.";
                TempData["Message-Class"] = "success";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error("Error updating information", e, this);
                TempData["Message"] = "Could not update information.";
                TempData["Message-Class"] = "danger";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var errors = GetErrorMessages(ModelState);

            TempData["Message"] = "The form values are not valid. Please fix the issues below.";
            TempData["Message"] += errors.ToString();
            TempData["Message-Class"] = "danger";
        }

        return new RedirectResult("~/Information");
    }
```

Comment: most likely because you're returning a `RedirectResult` which returns a url that the browser then redirects to, which is a brand new request.. You should probably try `RedirectToAction` or just return `View`

Comment: can you show where you are trying to access the TempData and getting a empty result? TempData's value will be cleared the first time you read from it. So if in your code somewhere does `var a = TempData["Message"]`, then subsequent access to TempData["Message"] will be empty

Comment: OP's code is correct, although it's simpler to write `return Redirect(~/Information);`.  This seems to be a sitecore issue, where the rendering pipeline kills TempData.  See https://sitecorecommunity.uservoice.com/forums/286986-product-sitecore-mvc/suggestions/7322135-fix-tempdata-weirdness